# Deploying to google app engine failed

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, wiki.js

I'm trying to deploy an app using https://wiki.js.org/

After getting everything set up locally, and then trying to deploy to our app engine project it will go through its motions and say it's Updating Service, which is the last step.

After a minute or so I will get this response:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error:

> wiki@1.0.78 start /app
> node wiki start

\u2714 Wiki.js has started successfully.
```

This is my app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
```

this is the package.json part with the "start" script

```
{
  "name": "wiki",
  "version": "1.0.78",
  "description": "A modern, lightweight and powerful wiki app built on NodeJS, Git and Markdown",
  "main": "wiki.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node wiki start",
    "stop": "node wiki stop",
    "restart": "node wiki restart",
    "build": "node tools/fuse",
    "dev": "node tools/fuse -d",
    "dev-configure": "node tools/fuse -c",
    "test": "jest",
    "postinstall": "opencollective postinstall"
  },
```

On my local environment, the process to start this app is to `run node wiki start`, but `npm start` also does the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am with GCP support. We have reproduced the issue a couple of times but it doesn’t look like an App Engine issue but one related to wiki.js. Only few third party libraries are [officially supported](https://cloud.google.com/terms/service-terms) by us and this is not one of them.

I have tried to solve the problem in a couple of ways anyway and I have found two suggestions in github (even if none worked for me):

**Solution 1**

Expand the memory adding the following lines to the app.yaml file [1](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/issues/175):

```
 resources:
     cpu: 2
     memory_gb: 4.0
     disk_size_gb: 20
```

**Solution 2**

Add the following lines to the app.yaml:

```
health_check:
        enable_health_check: False
```

Try it and best of lucks!

Comment: I think this may have worked, thank you so much! I also changed my package.json start script to do node server instead. also I changed the host to match the link for the app engine. But I think it was probably your answer. thanks again!

Comment: Hi, our project is incurring a lot of fees. Can you check out my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585757/google-app-engine-high-costs