# Google App Engine High Costs

Tags: google-app-engine

I recently asked a question: [Deploying to google app engine failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50219694/deploying-to-google-app-engine-failed)

I got my app deployed, however, we are incurring a large sum for this project. (wiki.js using third-party DB mLab).

I'm wondering if it has to do with the config I put in app.yaml, namely, the memory expansion and resources

This is what the google support person said: to add:

```
resources:
     cpu: 2
     memory_gb: 4.0
     disk_size_gb: 20

health_check:
        enable_health_check: False
```

My app.yaml (from google console) is:

```
runtime: nodejs
api_version: '1.0'
env: flexible
threadsafe: true
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 2
  max_num_instances: 20
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.5
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 4
  disk_size_gb: 20
health_check:
  enable_health_check: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Support person here again!

Find a detailed description of costs going to `Google Cloud Platform Console home` --> `Billing` --> `View detailed charges` or following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/view-history). Update the post with the expensive fields without sharing private data, please, so I can understand what is going on.

Find general information about quotas [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas).

P.S.: I found a couple of solutions and I suggested you to TRY them since they weren't working for me.

Comment: thanks, i'll get back to you on this. in the meantime, maybe you can answer another GAE question? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50627345/php-mail-wont-work-on-google-app-engine-flex-no-errors-displayed