# Php Mail wont work on Google App Engine Flex (no errors displayed)

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have a wordpress site running on Google App Engine flex. I'm trying to use the php mail() function for a simple contact form.

I have a block like so:

```
   if ( mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
      //stuff
   } else {
      error_reporting(-1);
      ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
      set_error_handler("var_dump");
      var_dump(error_get_last());
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r (error_get_last());
      echo '</pre>';
   }
```

I've tried using different $from emails with no luck. I get a NULL error message displayed in response. These are settings i'm using. I've tried using my admin @gmail account and now switched to the appsot@gservice. I don't see any mail related items logged in dashboard

```
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$from = "my-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com";
$subject = "New Application";
$message = 'test';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$from."\r\n"."X-Mailer: php";
```

Keep in mind this is the flex environment. Google only seems to have guides on using third party services for sending bulk email.

this mail function should work right? Do I have to edit my app.yaml or php.ini?

App.yaml

```
runtime: php
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(htm|html|css|js)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg))$
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg))$
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-includes/images/media/(.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg))$
  static_files: wordpress/wp-includes/images/media/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-includes/images/media/.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1
  secure: always

- url: /wp-admin/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-login.php
  script: wordpress/wp-login.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-cron.php
  login: admin

- url: /xmlrpc.php
  script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php

- url: /wp-(.+).php
  script: wordpress/wp-\1.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: wordpress/index.php

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: myproject-:us-east4:my-instance

runtime_config:
  document_root: wordpress
  skip_lockdown_document_root: true

env_variables:
  WHITELIST_FUNCTIONS: escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,exec,pclose,popen,shell_exec,phpversion,php_uname
```

php.ini

```
extension=bcmath.so
extension=gd.so
zend_extension=opcache.so
short_open_tag=On
upload_max_filesize = 200M
google_app_engine.disable_readonly_filesystem = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use App Engine Mail service outside standard environment. I literally cite the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/migrating#mail):

> The App Engine Mail service is not available outside the standard
> environment. You will need to use a third-party mail provider such as
> [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/), [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/), or [Mailjet](https://www.mailjet.com/) to send email. All of
> these services offer APIs to send email from applications running
> anywhere.
>
> The following guides show how to use these services with the flexible
> environment:
>
> [Sending emails with SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/sending-emails-with-sendgrid)
>
> [Sending emails with Mailgun](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/sending-emails-with-mailgun)
>
> [Sending emails with Mailjet](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/sending-emails-with-mailjet)

Comment: thanks for your response. I thought that was referring to their mail api service. it was confusing because they recommend using those third-party services that are mainly used to send bulk email and all I needed was a simple mail() to specified emails. thanks again